# Cross platform Encryption / Decryption applications for secure file transport

Tags: security, encryption

I have a client who is in need of a file based encryption / decryption application to be used between Linux / Windows 2003 Server.  The goal is to have a single file compressed nightly on a linux platform and secured using a script, transmitted over FTP, decrypted on the Windows 2003 server and available for other import routines such as SSIS, etc.

The file can remain unencrypted on each end after transport, the desire is mainly to keep the file secure during transport.  Firewall rules and the fact that IIS6 doesn't support SFTP eliminate SFTP as an option.  Simplicity is the primary focus here, so complex security options or heavyweight libraries cannot be used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [GnuPG](http://gnupg.org/), it's cross platform and since you are only sending files internally you don't really need a certificate signed by a big-name certificate authority.

Comment: And: It's [FLOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open_source_software)! Which is probably the most important criteria for encryption software.

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use our [OpenPGP task for SSIS](http://www.eldos.com/sbbsrv/ssis-pgp-task.php) when you need to load the protected data into SSIS.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at PGP:

http://www.pgpi.org/doc/overview/
http://www.pgpi.org/products/pgp/versions/freeware/
http://www.pgpi.org/doc/

Answer (score 1):

To GnuPG I would add [Thawte](http://thawte.com) (or similar) s/mime keys for email.

GnuPG has executables for every major platform and most email clients support s/mime keys for encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Try R10Cipher. 
Cross Platform,
384 Bit, 
Handles Text and Files,
*Very* Simple to use and inexpensive
http://www.r10cipher.com

Disclaimer:  It's produced by my company, Arten Science.